# error: cannot find symbol for String Array when placed in a loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program where a user can input a number of questions (NoQuestions) and then later is prompted for marks in a format "x,x,x"

I want to save the "x" in a array, and think a string array using the scan.next().split would work best.

I initiate the String[] Marks inside the for loop, and when testing to check if it has worked, it throws an error.

i think its probably a simple fix but Im not able to spot it.

```
for (int i=1; i < NoQuestions; i++){
    System.out.print("Enter Q" + 1 +": ");
    String[] Marks = scan.next().split(",");
}

System.out.println(Marks[2]);
```

error: cannot find symbol

Comment: please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the Marks outside of the for loop.  Move the Marks above the for loop, assign the value in the for loop. Then you can access outside of it. Also, please go through the scopes in java programming..